# How do I identify distinct combinations across array-columns and then unnest in sql presto

Tags: sql, presto

I have a database called programs created as

```
    CREATE TABLE programs (
            name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
            role varchar(200) NOT NULL,
            section text[] NOT NULL,
            sub_section text[] NOT NULL,
            title text[] NOT NULL
            );
    INSERT INTO programs (name, role, section, sub_section, title) VALUES 
            ('John','Lead','{"VII","VII","VII"}','{"A","A","C"}','{"STUDY","STUDY","STUDY"}'), 
            ('Olga','Member','{"VII","VII"}','{"A","A"}','{"STUDY","STUDY"}'),
            ('Ben','Co-Lead','{"XI","X"}','{"A","B"}','{"STUDY","TRAVEL"}'),
            ('Ana','Member','{"VII","II","VI"}','{"A","ALL","B"}','{"STUDY","STUDY","TRAVEL"}');
```

Here's what the table looks like

```
| name | role    | section      | sub_section | title                    |
| ---- | ------- | ------------ | ----------- | ------------------------ |
| John | Lead    | VII,VII,VII  | A,A,C       | STUDY,STUDY,STUDY        |
| Olga | Member  | VII,VII      | A,A         | STUDY,STUDY              |
| Ben  | Co-Lead | XI,X         | A,B         | STUDY,TRAVEL             |
| Ana  | Member  | VII,II,VI    | A,ALL,B     | STUDY,STUDY,TRAVEL       |
```

I want to identify distinct combinations across the section, sub-section, and title columns, as well as unnesting to get this as output

```
| name  | role    | section.sub_section | title                    |
| ----  | ------- | ------------------- | ------------------------ |
| John  | Lead    | VII.A               | STUDY
| John  | Lead    | VII.C               | STUDY
| Olga  | Member  | VII.A               | STUDY
| Ben   | Co-Lead | XI.A                | STUDY
| Ben   | Co-Lead | X.B                 | TRAVEL
| Ana   | Member  | VII.A               | STUDY
| Ana   | Member  | II.ALL              | STUDY
| Ana   | Member  | VI.B                | TRAVEL
```

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm really struggling with getting desired output. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You desired data does not show "combinations across the section, sub-section, and title columns", it seems that you require to match corresponding array based on positions, so you can just [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) and group by fields which you want to distinct on.

Assuming that corresponding columns contain arrays of varchars (if not - you will need to use some string functions to convert them):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (name, role, section, sub_section, title) AS (
    VALUES  ('John','Lead',array['VII','VII','VII'],array['A','A','C'],array['STUDY','STUDY','STUDY']), 
            ('Olga','Member',array['VII','VII'],array['A','A'],array['STUDY','STUDY']),
            ('Ben','Co-Lead',array['XI','X'],array['A','B'],array['STUDY','TRAVEL']),
            ('Ana','Member',array['VII','II','VI'],array['A','ALL','B'],array['STUDY','STUDY','TRAVEL'])

) 

--query
select name,
    role,
    sec || '.' || sub_sec "section.sub_section",
    t title
from dataset
    cross join unnest(section, sub_section, title) as t(sec, sub_sec, t)
group by name, role, sec, sub_sec, t
order by name
```

Output:

| name | role | section.sub_section | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ana | Member | VII.A | STUDY |
| Ana | Member | II.ALL | STUDY |
| Ana | Member | VI.B | TRAVEL |
| Ben | Co-Lead | XI.A | STUDY |
| Ben | Co-Lead | X.B | TRAVEL |
| John | Lead | VII.A | STUDY |
| John | Lead | VII.C | STUDY |
| Olga | Member | VII.A | STUDY |